# Missing report folders in SSRS for new project in new project collection

Tags: tfs

Environment consists of TFS 2015 Update 3. I created new team project collection and new team project based on Scrum.
     My question is related to the Reports.
     I see fewer reports on the SSRS side for this new team project than in the existing team projects which are being created in the existing team collections.
In this new team project from the newly created project collection on the SSRS side I only see following folders:

1. Builds folder with 2 reports: Build Success over time and Build summary
2. Tests folder with 2 reports: Test Case Readiness and Test Plan Progress
3. In the root of this team project SSRS folder, I also see “Backlog Overview”, “Release Burndown”, “Sprint Burndown” and “Velocity” reports.

Does it look OK?

When checking on the existing team projects which are being created in existing project collections, these also contain 3 extra folders: Bugs, Dashboards and Project Management folders ( each folder containing reports) but do not contain the 4 reports at the root level as per point 3. the original collections were created in tfs 2010 which we upgraded to 2015

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using different process template when you create team projects.

If you use **Scrum** Process Template, you'll see Builds folder, Tests folder, and “Backlog Overview”, “Release Burndown”, “Sprint Burndown” and “Velocity” reports.

If you use **Agile** or **CMMI** process template, you'll see Builds, Tests, Bugs, Dashboards and Project Management folders.